# Using range in List:Gen to iterate through various values

Tags: perl

I am trying to use [List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen) to iterate through an array with elements:

```
[0,  5000, 10000, ... 20000]
```

But the following code gives an error

```
use List::Gen;

my $nsamps = range 0, 5000, 20000;

for( $nsamp ($nsamps) { 
     print $nsamp
 }
```

The error is:

```
$nsamp requires explicit package ...
```

Why?

Comment: Also, you probably want `@$nsamps` in your for loop, since that is an array reference, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

You never declared `$nsamp`.

Also, have a stray `(`.

Finally, your indenting is wonky.

Fixed:

```
for my $nsamp ($nsamps) { 
    print $nsamp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But something is still missing. I get odd values in the output

Comment: @user273158: sounds like a different question would be appropriate for that

Answer (score 2):

To use [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen)'s range function, the step size is provided as the third argument:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';
use List::Gen;

my $nsamp = range 0, 20_000, 5_000 ;

say for @$nsamp;  # 0
                  # 5000
                  # 10000
                  # 15000
                  # 20000

# Or, for a faster equivalent

while ( my ( $num ) = $nsamp->() ) {
    say $num;
}
```